# Mongodb lookup to get single element instead of object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database, mongodb

my collection:

```
groups : [{_id: 001, name: ABC, type: a}, {_id: 002, name: DEF, type: b}]
```

I'm doing the below coding to get result in mongodb:

```
  .aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'groups',
      localField: 'groupId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'groupName'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$groupName',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: 
      groupName: {
        name: 1
      }
   }
```

The result I get from the above coding is :

```
groupName: Object { name: "ABC" }
```

But I don't want the `ABC` to be as an object.
I want my result to be single element:

```
groupName: "ABC"
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) you can achieve your expected result.

```
  .aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'groups',
      localField: 'groupId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'groupName'
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$groupName',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: 
      {groupName: "$groupName.name"}
   }
```